# Why use JSON (objects) and not standard ArrayLists?

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I commonly see data stored in JSON objects/arrays in open sourced Android code.

Why/When should I use JSON over normal Java ArrayLists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is a standard for transferring data between servers. It's a format that can be understood by any language, whether it be Java, C#, PHP, Python, Ruby, or JavaScript. Since it's a widely recognized format, it's much easier to work with JSON.

Many Android apps do communicate with a server, so it was probably easier for those developers to transfer the data to and from their server, which may or may not have been using Java.

Comment: I especially loved the correct usage of the subjunctive in this post.

Answer (score 2):

If your client android application need data from a web service, then JSON data type can be used instead of XML because it's less character cost and it's easier to read